# Why am I receiving this FileNotFoundException and how can I resolve it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, log4j, tomcat7

I am trying to implement Log4J logging on my tomcat server (we have this in place in our local environment and I am prepping to migrate our services to AWS).  I have followed the [instructions found in the Tomcat7 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) and have everything in its rightful location.  When I try to start Tomcat I receive a `FileNotFound` exception in the log and the application fails to start.

```
Configuration error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:466)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:311)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:320)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:318)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:318)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:300)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:265)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1468)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1466)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:204)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.getLogger(Jdk14Logger.java:164)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.<init>(Jdk14Logger.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:49)
```

I suspect this is because there is something non-standard about our Tomcat7 configuration, but the initial setup on AWS was performed by a consultant who is no longer available to me.  Where can I look and what should I check for to correct this issue?

Good answers should not instruct me to put a `logging.properties` file in `/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/` because that is not how my existing configuration works (and I don't have this problem there) **and the tomcat7 documentation explicitly tells the user to delete `logging.properties` from `../conf/`**, unless there is some caveat which requires it that is not expressed in the tomcat documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the problem was related to the `tomcat7` bash shell script (either written or updated by aforementioned consultant).  This script was hardcoded to check for the `logging.properties` file in a Java option (`-Djava.util.logging.config.file="${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/logging.properties"`).

Removing this line from the tomcat7 script has corrected the problem.